# How to transform complex Java collection into other one?

Tags: java, data-structures, lambda, collections, java-8

I have the following String table:

```
"KEYS","VALUES_A","VALUES_B"
"Key_A","anyval_1","anyval_4"
"Key_A","anyval_2","anyval_5"
"Key_B","anyval_3","anyval_6"
```

currently in this data structure in Java:

```
List<Map<String,String>> [
    {"KEYS"="Key_A"}, {"VALUES_A"="anyval_1"}, {"VALUES_B"="anyval_4"},
    {"KEYS"="Key_A"}, {"VALUES_A"="anyval_2"}, {"VALUES_B"="anyval_5"},
    {"KEYS"="Key_B"}, {"VALUES_A"="anyval_3"}, {"VALUES_B"="anyval_6"}
]
```

I am looking for a solution that transforms the structure above into the following one:

```
Map<Map<String, String>, List<List<String>> {
    {{"Key_A", "VALUES_A"}, ["anyval_1", "anyval_2"]},
    {{"Key_A", "VALUES_B"}, ["anyval_4", "anyval_5"]},
    {{"Key_B", "VALUES_A"}, ["anyval_3"]},
    {{"Key_B", "VALUES_B"}, ["anyval_6"]}
}
```

What is the simplest way to do this in Java8?

Comment: Using a `Map<String, String>` as a key in your map sounds like a bad idea...

Comment: This seems like a very complex structure to be storing solely in collections, have you considered just having a class that captures the structure you're after?

Comment: Map being used as a key for another map is not a good idea. Can you explain your scenario? You might be able to implement your functionality using less complex data structures.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, you want to use a pair of `String` values as the key, with a list of `String`s as the value.

As mentioned in the comments, you should probably create a custom class containing the pair that you want.  To use the object as a key in a `HashMap` you must override `hashcode()` and `equals()`.  Here's a simple implementation:

```
public class MyKey {
    final String key;
    final String value;

    public MyKey(String key, String value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((key == null) ? 0 : key.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((value == null) ? 0 : value.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        MyKey other = (MyKey) obj;
        if (key == null) {
            if (other.key != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!key.equals(other.key))
            return false;
        if (value == null) {
            if (other.value != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!value.equals(other.value))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then you can simply define your map like this:

```
Map<MyKey, List<String>> foo = ...
```

and iterate over your table rows, creating `new MyKey(key, "VALUES_A")` to use as the key for the first value, and `new MyKey(key, "VALUES_B")` to use as the key for the second value.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I can agree with this: "Using a Map<String, String> as a key in your map sounds like a bad idea..."